# catboost R categorical conversion to numbers

Tags: r, categorical-data, catboost

If I have a data frame with, let's say, factors in columns 1 and 2 and the label in column 3 , is there any difference between:

```
train_pool <- catboost.load_pool(data = training[,1:2], label = training[,3])
```

And

```
train_pool <- catboost.load_pool(data = training[,1:2], 
                                 label = training[,3], cat_features=c(1,2))
```

This is, does it autodetect that the columns 1&2 are factors and transform it to numbers even when i do not expicitly declare it in the `catboost.load_pool`?

b) Is there anyway in the R package to get the matrix with the categorical values transformed to numbers?

Answer (score 0):

It may be offtop, but for my classification task i have category labels and for transform into integer I used following code:

```
train_pool <- catboost.load_pool(data = train[-1],
                                 label = as.numeric(as.factor(train[,1]))-1)
```

Before transformation they look like:
[image]

You can try manually transform features.